# Too Many Redirects Error. When trying to redirect a url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file has this code:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

During Seo, my site shows 2 URL duplicate error as:-
https://example.net/contact-us.php  & https://example.net/contact-us points to the same resource. So, we need to redirect the URL. For that, I wrote this code:-

Redirect 301 /contact-us.php https://example.net/contact-us/

The problem is It shows too many redirects Error. Kindly Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have 2 rules. 1 to redirect no extension to php file and 1 to redirect php to no extension if someone types it in. You should not need that`Redirect 301` rule.

I would have my rules like below.

Replace these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

with this

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect a direct request for the php file to no extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/([^\s]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. It did the job well. I was trying to figure the error from the past 2 days. U solved it. So, a big thanks.  I need one more help. Could you point me to a resource that explains to me how to use .haccess and how to write its rules?

Comment: Just use the Apache docs to understand the syntax and how mod_rewrite works. then it's a bit of trial and error some times but study other SO answers to get more know how as well.